# React.js error page renders in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

When there is an error because of X, in Firefox I can only detect this by looking at the console. The components still render. I've had this happen on other projects too, on different computers, making me think this is something I am going to have to address specifically for FF.

Versus in Chrome, where the helpful "error component" (IDK what this is called) renders, definitely making the developer aware. I've attached an image of this.

It's the screen that says this at the bottom: "This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production. Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message."

I really want this to appear in FF. Any clue how? I do have React devtools installed, but that is not the thing driving this, as you don't even need that tool in Chrome to see this rendered.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with react dev tools?

Comment: @RobTerrell This helpful error modal renders without React devtools, in my brief experiment. Turning it off in Chrome, you still get it to appear. One thing I will try is testing this on a bare Firefox.

Comment: I figured it out, @RobTerrell. The problem was an extension that was somehow mucking with this. Disabling 1 extension solved it.

Comment: awesome good find

Answer (score 0):

This was the cause of an extension getting in the way.

I solved this by disabling a handful of extensions at a time until I got the `error screen` to load. Then I reversed the process until I narrowed it down to one extension.

The culprit was a form auto-fill extension.